# ValueError facing in implementing one hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

Below is the implemention of one hot encoding with many categories under each column.

```
Ttop_10_LMR = [x for x in tdata.Loan_Amount_Requested.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).index]
```

**Ttop_10_LMR**  variable gives the top 10 frequent values in Loan_Amount_Requested column.

```
def one_hot_top_x(df, variable, top_x_labels):
    for label in top_x_labels:
        df[variable+'_'+str(label)] = np.where(data[variable]==label, 1, 0)
```

**one_hot_top_x** func will add new columns to *tdata* Dataframe by replacing top_x_labels with 1 and 0.

But when i run the below code,

```
one_hot_top_x(tdata, 'Loan_Amount_Requested', Ttop_10_LMR)
```

Getting as ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[variable+'_'+str(label)] = np.where(tdata[variable]==label, 1, 0)
```

instead of tdata given as data :)